# Why is my Laravel factory unable to find my model?

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a Business model using `artisan make:model command`, a model factory and a seed method. When running my seed method I get the following error:

> InvalidArgumentException Unable to locate factory with name [default]
>   [App\Business].

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Business model:

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Business extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];

    public function resources()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Resource');
    }

}
```

**Business Factory**

```
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(Business::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->company,
    ];
});
```

**Seeder Method**

```
$business = factory(App\Business::class, 50)
                   ->create()
                   ->each(function ($u) {
                        $u->resources()->save(factory(App\Resource::class)->make());
                    });
```

Comment: In your "business factory", add `use App\Business;` after the `use Faker\Generator as Faker;` line.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try to `composer dump-autoload`

Sometimes, it helps in such situations.

And make sure that when you declare such factory: `$factory->define(Business::class,...` your Business class is correctly imported, or consider changing it to `App\Business`.

Comment: I have tried `composer dump-autoload` and am still having issues. I have also imported the Model using `use Business;`

Comment: @Imran try `use App\Business`

Comment: And this followed by `composer dump-autoload`?